# Can you use both the Pineberry Hat+ Bottom and Hat+ Top?

Tags: pi-5

There are two products made by Pineberry,

- [HatDrive! Bottom (NVMe 2230, 2242, 2280 GEN 3) for Raspberry Pi 5](https://pineberrypi.com/products/hatdrive-bottom-2230-2242-2280-for-rpi5)
- [HatDrive! Top (NVMe 2230, 2242 GEN 3) for Raspberry Pi 5](https://pineberrypi.com/products/hat-top-2230-2240-for-rpi5)

Are both of these supported at the same? What happens if you install and try to use both of them?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Pi5 has just 1 PCI connector so you cannot connect 2 devices

Comment: there are devices out there that claim to be able to connect two nvmes, https://www.aliexpress.us/item/3256806346837692.html

Comment: @EvanCarroll The question was about 2 boards, *not* about 2 drives on a single board. I haven't delved into it but I think I read that you may not be be to boot from these boards

Comment: I'm just saying for completeness it maybe better to explain what isn't possible, because if 2 nvme's are possible on one board, why not two separate boards? May also be better to explain why booting is then impossible.